# Чи має запозичений термін “патерн” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: переклад, from-english, синоніми, терміни, відповідник

Зіткнувся з таким терміном як **патерн/и [програмування]**.

Як [зазначає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)) Вікіпедія, загальне значення цього слова є:

> **Патерн** (англ. pattern — взірець, зразок, маска, шаблон) — об'єкт з якого робляться копії або набори повторюваних об'єктів.
>   Патерн — запозичене слово. Слово «pattern» використовується як термін в кількох західних дисциплінах і технологіях, звідки воно і проникло в наше мовне середовище. Сенс терміна «патерн» завжди вужче, ніж просто «зразок», і варіюється в залежності від галузі знань, в якій використовується.

але при переході, на більш узагальнюючий термін **[патерн (інформатика)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)**, який є найбільш наближеним до *програмування* отримуємо вже цілих три слова:

> **Шаблони проектування програмного забезпечення** (англ. software design patterns) — ефектні способи вирішення задач проектування програмного забезпечення. Шаблон не є закінченим зразком, який можна безпосередньо транслювати в програмний код. Об'єктно-орієнтований шаблон найчастіше є зразком вирішення проблеми і відображає відношення між класами та об'єктами, без вказівки на те, як буде зрештою реалізоване це відношення.

У [Вікісловнику](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0), [e2u.org.ua](https://e2u.org.ua/) слово "патерн" взагалі відсутнє.

Пошук у словниках синонімів на ресурсах [Синоніми.укр](https://%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B8.%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80/%D0%9F/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD), [Rozum.org.ua](http://www.rozum.org.ua/search) і  результатів не дає.

Чи існує в українській мові якийсь сталий термін?
*Шаблони* — це якось узагальнено... 
А якщо так, то чи можливо його використання на заміну запозиченому *патерн*?

Comment: Навіщо взагалі намагатися замінити слово патерн?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте спершу глянемо як слово "pattern" взагалі можливо перекласти українською (допоможе нам у цьому ось [цей сайт](https://www.m-translate.com.ua/en-uk/word-patterns-translation#)): [викрійка](http://sum.in.ua/s/vykrijka) (згідно до СУМу - стосується одягу, взуття), [зразок](http://sum.in.ua/s/zrazok), [модель](http://sum.in.ua/s/modelj), модло, [схема](http://sum.in.ua/s/skhema), [узор](http://sum.in.ua/s/uzor), [шаблон](http://sum.in.ua/s/shablon).

Отож, як на мене, а також згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)), значень у слова "патерн" є так багато, що якогось одного синоніма ми не можемо знайти в українській мові, тому переклад цього слова та його заміна буде залежати від к
онтексту. Однак, на ті й же Вікіпедії даються можливі відповідники - взірець, зразок, маска, шаблон.

Згідно до цього [сайту](https://refactoring.guru/uk/design-patterns), коли ми говоримо про "патерн" у контексті **ІТ**, то ми можемо замінити його словом "**шаблон**", у контексті дизайну - "**повторюваний елемент**", а в **медицині** - це **сукупність ознак або симптомів**, тобто замість «**патерни** рухових і чуттєвих розладів при патології нервових структур в дистальних відділах верхньої кінцівки» можна сказати «**ознаки** рухових і чуттєвих розладів при патології нервових структур в дистальних відділах верхньої кінцівки» ([джерело](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD#%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD_%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96)). Коли говоримо про в'язання - хорошим відповідником буде "**схема" або ж "**схема візерунку**", а в **психології** "патерн" - це те саме, що і "**стереотип**".

Заглянемо також на [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/patern), де серед відповідників є: взірець, модло, частик, кшталт, шаблон, викрійка, закономірність ("у цих даних простежується певна закономірність"), візерунок.

Чи може "шаблон" бути відповідником до слова "патерн". Цитую ваше визначення останнього:

> **Патерн** (англ. pattern — взірець, зразок, маска, шаблон) — об'єкт з
>   якого робляться копії або набори повторюваних об'єктів.

Дивимося можливі значення слова "**шаблон**":

> Пристрій, за допомогою якого виготовляють однакові формою, розміром і
>   т. ін. деталі та вироби при їх серійному чи масовому виробництві.
>
> Зразок, взятий для наслідування; штамп, банальність.

Тому гадаю, що так, однак не вважаю їх абсолютними синонімами, проте, коли ми говоримо про "паттерн" в контексті програмування (як я вже писав вище) ми можемо замінити його "шаблоном", але для того, щоб надати точнішого значення ми додаємо ще й інші слова, того й отримуємо: "Шаблони Проектування Програмного Забезпечення" чи "Шаблони Програмування" ([джерело](http://www.vitaliypodoba.com/2014/06/programming-patterns-intro/)).

Comment: Англійською «шаблони проектування програмного забезпечення» теж повністю називаються «software design patterns» (тобто тут не 4 слова замість одного, а 1 слово («шаблони») замість одного («patterns»)).

Comment: Мiнус на вiдповiдi мiй тому що у психології слово патерн це не те саме що й стереотип.

Comment: Згідно до Вікіпедії це ці слова можна вживати як відповідники, у вас є якісь джерела, які б спростовували цей факт?

Comment: @Анатолій, в цьому і проблема - це як раз не факт, а тільки лише твердження. І сама по собі Вікіпедія авторитет сумнівний, якщо там не вказано посилання на щось авторитетне. Лінк - [стереотип](http://elibrary.kubg.edu.ua/5980/3/O_Serhieienkova_IL.pdf#page=295&zoom=50,-291,354), [патерн](http://elibrary.kubg.edu.ua/5980/3/O_Serhieienkova_IL.pdf#page=200&zoom=50,-291,719).  Я не заперечую, що в деяких кейсах ці слова можуть бути взаємозамінними, але вважати їх рівнозначними - помилка. До речі використовуйте символ @ і нік учасника, щоб йому прийшла нотифікація(повідомлення).

Comment: І все ж, з усією повагою до вас, підтвердження того, що я написав, також можна знайти і в [словнику](http://slovopedia.org.ua/39/53407/260866.html) іншомовних соціокультурних термінів.

Comment: Ваше крайня посилання про соціологію. У будь-якому випадку ми тут просто ділимося думками і мати різні трактування - абсолютно нормально. Ви навели свої аргументи, я - свої. Просто я завжди коментую кожен мінус.